# Where are data from getPurchases() stored (when device is offline)?

Tags: android, subscription, android-billing

So there is this function https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_reference#getPurchases

and apparently it's able to return me the valid subscriptions even  when the user is offline. Can I rely on this method to always tell be which subscriptions are valid? Or is the data stored somewhere in some cache, so after a day or two it gets removed.

To introduce you to my problem, I want to be able to tell which subscription is still active (hasn't expired) even if the device is offline, so i'm making sure this is a viable way.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the incomplete answer, I don't have the exact reference to this, but so far as I know, the purchased in-app products are cached internally by the Google Play Store and/or Google Play Services.

I am just telling from the experience, just answering because I haven't faced any problems while providing paid features to the offline users. So I guess, you can rely on this method.